# lua gsub special replacement producing invalid capture index

Tags: regex, lua, replace, gsub

I have a piece of lua code (executing in Corona):

```
local loginstr = "emailAddress={email} password={password}"
print(loginstr:gsub( "{email}", "tester@test.com" ))
```

This code generates the error:

invalid capture index

While I now know it is because of the curly braces not being specified appropriately in the gsub pattern, I don't know how to fix it.

How should I form the gsub pattern so that I can replace the placeholder string with the email address value?

I've looked around on all the lua-oriented sites I can find but most of the documentation seems to revolve around unassociated situations.

Comment: You are not, by any chance, encoding the e-mail for URL, are you? The `%40` in the encoded string would cause the error for sure. As it stands, the above is valid for standard LUA.

Comment: @vhallac: You should put that down as an answer: http://ideone.com/fMRZ5

Comment: @muistooshort I would, but there is no indication that the e-mail address is encoded.

Comment: @vhallac: But if the variable really is `loginurl` and the code in the question is just demo code then your URL encoding guess could be dead on. Your call of course.

Comment: @vhallac you are right, the email will come from a web form. How would I ensure the encoded @ (as %40) doesn't cause a problem? And, for that matter, why does it? Thank you all :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I've suggested in the comments above, when the e-mail is encoded as a URL parameter, the %40 used to encode the '@' character will be used as a capture index. Since the search pattern doesn't have any captures (let alone 40 of them), this will cause a problem.

There are two possible solutions: you can either decode the encoded string, or encode your replacement string to escape the '%' character in it. Depending on what you are going to do with the end result, you may need to do both.

the following routine (I picked up from [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringRecipes) - not tested) can decode an encoded string:

```
function url_decode(str)
  str = string.gsub (str, "+", " ")
  str = string.gsub (str, "%%(%x%x)",
      function(h) return string.char(tonumber(h,16)) end)
  str = string.gsub (str, "\r\n", "\n")
  return str
end
```

For escaping the % character in string `str`, you can use:

```
str:gsub("%%", "%%%%")
```

The '%' character is escaped as '%%', and it needs to be ascaped on both the search pattern and the replace pattern (hence the amount of % characters in the replace).

Comment: Upvoted you months ago, then came back to this answer today while searching for a similarly cryptic error w `gsub` and this fixed it again :)

Comment: Can someone explain the second gsub? I'm totally lost.  How is function(h) working?  How is h passed to the function? And is %x%x is just find one of anything, twice? 

http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your problem isn't that you're trying to `gsub` on `loginurl` rather than `loginstr`?

Your code gives me this error (see http://ideone.com/wwiZk):

```
lua: prog.lua:2: attempt to index global 'loginurl' (a nil value)
```

and that sounds similar to what you're seeing. Just fixing it to use the right variable:

```
print(loginstr:gsub( "{email}", "tester@test.com" ))
```

says (see http://ideone.com/mMj0N):

```
emailAddress=tester@test.com password={password}
```

as desired.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I'm thinking of using the unescape function found here: http://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html Do you know why having an escaped string in the replacement string is a problem?

Comment: @Matt: I think a `%4` in the replacement will be interpreted to mean "the 4th capture group" so you need the `%40` to be `%%40` or `@` before you call `gsub`. If you put your string through that `unescape` function first you'll get an `@` and the `gsub` should work. I think you should wait until vhallac gets back and puts his comment down as an answer before you accept anything though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in **value** part so You need to escape value with: **value:gsub("%%", "%%%%")**.

Example of replacing "some value" in json:

```
local resultJSON = json:gsub(, "\"SOME_VALUE\"", value:gsub("%%", "%%%%"))
```